# how to make all columns is return TRUE

Tags: r

I have this command script.

```
d10_df.row <- sqlQuery(conn, sqlq, as.is = c(T,T)
```

where, `T` has `TRUE` value, and all the `T` was based on how many columns that I have. In this example, I have 2 columns.
My question is, do R have any function which can return `TRUE` for all columns. So if I have 5 columns, I don't have to define `c(T,T,T,T,T)` but only `c(TRUE)` but for all columns that return or has.

Could someone help me about this.

Comment: If you know the number of columns in advance you can use `rep(T,5)`.

Comment: Would it not be the case that if you want `TRUE` for all columns that `as.is = TRUE` would suffice as the `TRUE` value would be recycled to be of appropriate length. 

As a minor point I would also suggest using `TRUE` explicitly rather than `T` as it is possible to set `T = FALSE` or `T=0` etc which would yield the possibility of passing an unintended value to the function.